# Is it possible to combine or mix Jenkins declarative and scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Our current pipeline is using declarative pipeline and it's pretty comprehensive but I would like to add nested parallel stages which aren't possible with declarative one. So I wonder if it's possible to mix two?

Comment: It is possible, actually every time you use a `script {...}` directive you are combining them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can only if you want to have external function inside step block. You cannot change the structure of the declarative syntax.

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage("test") {
            steps {
                script {
                    test_function()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
def test_function() { println("hello World")}
```